# Can Ninject inject a class and make it reference the target class as a back reference?

Tags: dependency-injection, webforms, ninject, presenter, ninject.web

I want to inject a presenter into my webform class. While doing so I would like the injected presenter to contain a reference to the view it is being injected into. Inject a class with a reference to the class it is injected into. Is it possible to do this with Ninject? When injecting into a webforms class, is the injection performed before the constructor is executed? Should I rather just inject the presenter and use the constructor to pass the view?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Ninject, but the normal way to break cyclic dependencies is by using Property Injection.

Comment: For webforms I have to use property injection anyways, but the problem is injecting an  object that has a reference to the class it is being injected into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For webforms this is not possible because the form is not created by ninject. You have to pass it manually to the presenter.

I think the solution is to use MVC there you have support for your problem form the framework. Webforms and MVC can be mixed. You can create new pages with MVC and still use the old webform ones. Whenyou have to change a webforms page then you better refactor it to MVC befor the change.

Comment: So, the closest I can get for webforms is property injection and the assign the view to the presenter inside the setter?

Comment: Exactly. But you should really go for MVC. There is no reason to use webforms anymore